# How to set google map apiKey as an environment variable to make secure in Asp.net - Angular application

Tags: asp.net, angular, google-maps-api-3, environment-variables

The google map is one of my app feature. Currently for testing, I keep the google apiKey in Angular client side, map.module.ts, as below:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AddressCoordsComponent, MapComponent...],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ 
      apiKey: 'AGdeXyCNkyatnhJcnYbdEf669_jVQ7rHYRSMG7Qs',
      libraries: ['geometry']
    })    
  ],
  exports: [....
```

Now in production, wondering how this key should be properly set to the appsetting.json and then called in this module of my application other than explicitly coded here?

Comment: what deployment tools you are using ?

Comment: Deploy (Reloaded) was used to deploy all files from my workspace to a remote Ubuntu server. Thanks Hafizi!

Answer (score 0):

For secure use of the apiKey, here is my alternative solution at the moment. Just go to my google account and set the website restrictions to my own website only. There is even an option to allow specific APIs that this key can call the key. With both setting, I believe my key should be safe now.